# Fetching mysql records from CakePHP with specific index

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using the following cakephp query to retrieve data from mysql:

```
    $tops = $this->PageBanner->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'PageBanner.status' => 1
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'PageBanner.page_url',
            'PageBanner.image',
            'PageBanner.logo',
            'PageBanner.logo_text',
            'PageBanner.content'
        )
    ));
```

This query returns me the following results:

```
  [0] => Array
    (
        [PageBanner] => Array
            (
                [page_url] => index
                [image] => home_banner.png
                [logo] => home_logo.png
                [logo_text] => abc 
                [content] => abc.
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [PageBanner] => Array
            (
                [page_url] => write_review
                [image] => kids2.png
                [logo] => home_logo.png
                [logo_text] => abc
                [content] => abc. 
            )

    )
```

But I want the data to be returned in the following format:

```
  [index] => Array
    (
                [page_url] => index
                [image] => home_banner.png
                [logo] => home_logo.png
                [logo_text] => abc
                [content] => abc.
    )

[write_review] => Array
    (
                [page_url] => write_review
                [image] => kids2.png
                [logo] => home_logo.png
                [logo_text] => abc
                [content] => abc. 
    )
```

I need page_url field content in place of Array index (e.i. 0, 1). Is that possible to get data in this format or I need to manually configure the arrays?

Comment: Cake won't do it for you. This is not a common way to retrieve data and it really doesn't make much more sense. Anyway, you can do it manually, this case doesn't have much complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = Set::combine($tops, '{n}.PageBanner.page_url', '{n}.PageBanner');
pr($result);
```